# Any addins for VS2010 to support VS2005 projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Some of the old projects in our company are left to be built with VS2005 in autobuild system (making them build correctly in 2010 cost time). Is it any addins for VS2010 that will allow to open VS2005 project and edit it's files without converting project file itself to VS2010 format (converting will kill autobuild)? Of course i can create a separate project named "xxx_vs2010.vcproj" for each of such products, but that will be a mess :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to consider is to target the VS2005 C++ toolchain from within VS2010.  See [Native Multi-Targeting](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx) and the [Project Upgrade Guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2010/03/02/visual-studio-2010-c-project-upgrade-guide.aspx).  That way, no need to modify source code to appease the VS2010 C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2):

---

No.